# react-native 0.46 link command quits after prompt?

Tags: react-native

After updating from 0.45 to 0.46, the `react-native link` command no longer seems to do anything in my project. I even tried re-creating a new app from scratch and found the same issue. Reproduced on Mac, and Windows 10 Ubuntu Bash.

I get the prompt asking the usual question, but it seems to exit without any error message right after. Using node 6.10.1 and npm 4.5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a confirmed bug in 0.46 that was fixed in 0.46.1:
https://twitter.com/grabbou/status/883358932907024386

It was caused by an inadvertent upgrade of the `inquirer` package, whose prompt function signature changed between versions (from a callback to a Promise):
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/352c3d97b3017ab91cfca15a8d54fb753edc7ed5